# How does the JVM initiate the fields in super and sub classes?

Tags: java, jvm, jls

Can any body tell why the output of following code is "null"? And what is the best way to construct a complex Object and delegate the details to their subclasses?

```
package com.test;

public class ClassA {

    ClassA() {
        initHeader();
        initBody();
        initFooter();
    }

    void initHeader() {}

    void initBody() {}

    void initFooter() {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClassB a = new ClassB();
        System.out.println(a.obj);
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA {

    public Object obj = null;

    ClassB() {
        super();
    }

    void initHeader() {
        obj = new Object();
    }

}
```

Comment: what is the best way to construct a *complex* Object...? --> Keep It Simple

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, the fields of `ClassA` are initialized.

The constructor of `ClassA` is then called, calling `ClassB.initHeader()`.

After that, fields of `ClassB` are initialized overriding what `initHeader()` had done.

Comment: Funny somebody downvoted the only right answer (almost: the constructor of ClassB is called but since it calls super the constructor of ClassA is also called)! If in doubt debugger is your friend - this is exactly what is happening. The voting is now 0 because of my upvote.

Comment: @mantrid I'm sure some efforts in writing a pretty (and readable) answer help.

Comment: So, what is the best practice to construct the complex objects to avoid this kind of confusion?

Comment: @AaronMao what you did was mostly good even if personally I try, whenever possible, to limit the use of complex initializations (or functions) using more than one hierarchical level. Just fix it by changing `public Object obj = null;` to `public Object obj;` (as was suggested by xvorsx).

Comment: @AaronMao: there is a general rule: avoid calling non-private/non-final methods from constructors.

Answer (score 1):

It's not correct that this code doesn't call `initHeader` from ClassB.
You can verify it by adding debug output to `initHeader` methods of both class.

`public Object obj = null;` contain two parts:

1. declaration `public Object obj`
2. execution `obj = null`

First part known when constructor runs (at this moment obj initialised as `null` by default)
Second part executed **after constructor**, so after `initHeader` and override obj.

Try just replace `public Object obj = null;` by `public Object obj;`

Comment: Actually, the second part executed **right after the super constructor** and then the sub class constructor executed.